# How to use dblink for update?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way I can use dblink to update a column from server1/database2 using the value from another table on server2/database2 ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better solution, but in the mean time you can try this.

```
SELECT INTO DUMMY dblink_connect('host=localhost  port=5432 dbname=DBNAME
                                  user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD');        
SELECT INTO DUMMY dblink_open('PARAMS', 'SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE');
LOOP
   SELECT INTO ONE_PARAM RES.VALUE
   FROM (
      SELECT * FROM dblink_fetch(''PARAMS'', 1) AS (VALUE VARCHAR(100))) RES;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
         /*DO UPDATE HERE*/ 
END LOOP;
SELECT INTO DUMMY dblink_close(''PARAMS'');
```